# Calculate the sum of each diagonal of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, diagonal

I have a matrix like A and I want to calculate the sum of each diagonal of this matrix and show it in a vector like Y.

```
A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]

Y=[3 8 15 12 7]
```

I know the code

```
[sum(diag(y,2)),sum(diag(y,1)),sum(diag(y,0)),sum(diag (y,-1)),sum(diag (y,-2))]
```

but i want to write it as a function.

Answer (score 5):

[`spdiags`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) can do exactly what you want:

```
dsum = sum(spdiags(A))
```

You can reverse the vector with [`fliplr`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) and create a function:

```
function dsum = diagsum(A)
    dsum = fliplr(sum(spdiags(A)));
end
```

**RESULT**

```
dsum =

    3    8   15   12    7
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
[r ,c]=size(A);
idx=bsxfun(@plus,(r:-1:1)',0:c-1);
s=flipud(accumarray(idx(:),A(:)));
```

Comparing this with `spdiags` that proposed in other answer this method performs much much better in Octave. **Benchmark:**

```
A = rand(1000);
disp('---------bsxfun+accumarray----------')
tic
    [r ,c]=size(A);
    idx=bsxfun(@plus,(r:-1:1)',0:c-1);
    s=flipud(accumarray(idx(:),A(:)));
toc
disp('---------spdiags----------')
tic
    dsum = fliplr(sum(spdiags(A)));
toc
```

**Result:**

```
---------bsxfun+accumarray----------
Elapsed time is 0.0114651 seconds.
---------spdiags----------
Elapsed time is 8.62041 seconds.
```

Comment: since matlab R2016b, you can now remove the use of `bsxfun` and directly use `(r:-1:1)' + (0:c-1)` :) !

Comment: @TwistedSim But as of 2018 [some seasoned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51060328/how-to-sum-parts-of-a-matrix-of-different-sizes-without-using-for-loops/51060619#comment89111415_51060619) MATLAB users prefer `bsxfun` over  implicit expansion! :)

Comment: When you come from a numpy background, it still make more sense to use broadcasting ;). And I now realize that I'm not the first one to say that... oopsidoopsi

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [the answer from rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999838/52738), you can also generate your indices using [`toeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) before applying [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[r, c] = size(A);
index = toeplitz(c:(r+c-1), c:-1:1);
Y = accumarray(index(:), A(:)).';
```